# Timesheet in Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to know if we have timesheet tracking on a day/individual basis capability available in Azure DevOps. I know there are 3rd party integrations available but

Q1. is there a market place extension available by MS itself?

Q2. If not, is there a feature roadmap for timesheet in AzDo services?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. As far as I know, there is no Microsoft extension for time tracking in Azure DevOps.
A2. I surely don't hope so. ^

^ My opinion: Azure DevOps is not meant to be a time tracking system. Furthermore, with agile development processes we're steering *away* from hours and moving into a more abstract way of estimating time with story points. Sure, we can register how many hours we spent on a task, but that should only be a rough number as far as I'm concerned.

I understand that knowing the amount of hours someone worked on a task/user story might be interesting, or maybe even necessary for things like billing. But I think that having time tracking be an integral part of your DevOps process probably makes the developers just write 8 hours a day on tasks, rendering all estimates and hours useless in the end.

Comment: I can't believe MS still haven't got a timer in Azure DevOps.  I was hoping to push for a return to using it.  So, a contrary opinion is needed here.  Businesses need the time info. A developer marking 8hrs on the clock is exhibiting the bad kind of lazy behaviour and is arguably a risk to the project and may be stealing company money.  Nobody spends 100% of a day on a task.  Managing the task timer is just part of the dev cycle and is as natural and obvious (to me) as opening your IDE, reading the ticket, writing notes and committing code.

Answer (score 0):

A1. No, MS does not have extensions for timesheets. I think, it`s available in Project Server/Online only.

A2. I did not see any plans to get this feature on Azure Devops. [Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline)